# Can i upload files to Heroku Free tier app?

Tags: python, heroku

I have word processing python script, user uploads the files through web ui and script do the processing, but can do file upload with Heroku Free account ?

If not then is it possible to use the containers(with free account) as a workaround ?

Comment: You can do a file upload with a free account as far as I know, but you need some cloud storage option because there is no local filesystem you can use on Heroku.

Comment: @mechanical_meat To run the script, files should be in the local filesystem, right ? then is it possible

Comment: The script is in the local filesystem, they have the ability to support that. But they do not support storing the uploads on their filesystem.

Comment: can i use containers as a workaround to that with free account ?

Comment: Ah, good question. I don't know. Maybe edit your question to add that option?

Comment: how about uploading the file to google drive or one drive then will it work, i mean can python script run on the file when file is on drive ?

Comment: I think that would work, but you're going to have to deal with all the infrastructure of Google. Something like S3 *might* be easier? Even easier, but I don't know if free, is to use add-on(s) within Heroku like redis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can upload files on Heroku (free) Dynos but they have an [ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem), which means all local changes are lost after redeployment.

It is a common practice in Heroku to use remote storage like S3 or Dropbox.

Check [Files on Heroku](https://medium.com/geekculture/files-on-heroku-cd09509ed285) to understand options and see examples.